# Watch MongoDB to return changes along with a specified field value instead of returning fullDocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, replicaset

I'm using `watch()` function of mongo to listen to changes made to a replicaSet, now I know I can get the whole document (fullDocument) by passing `{ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }` to the watch method,
like :-

```
someModel.watch({ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' })
```

But what I really want to do is, get just one extra field which isn't changed every time a new update is made.

Let's say a field called `'user_id'`, currently I only get the `updatedFields` and the `fullDocument` which contains the `'user_id'` along with a lot of other data which I would like to avoid.

What I have researched so far is `Aggregation pipeline` but couldn't figure out a way to implement it.

Can anybody help me figure out a way to this?

Comment: Does your example even work? According to the [watch method documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/), `fullDocument` is an option, and should be given in the second argument of the method.

Comment: You can project with change streams.

Comment: Hi @noam it does work, I'm passing fullDocument as the only option. And since the method excepts an object and not positional arguments, it is ok if you only pass one key.

Comment: Yes sir @D.SM thats what I tried but couldn't get it working. To pass $project in the aggregate pipeline, since $project lets you choose which keys to hide or display.

Comment: I would also like to point out that, I'm not trying to show/hide an updated field, rather want to show an unchanged field with every update. Currently, I can get that field from the fullDocument, I want to reduce the amount of data mongo sends back to my node server which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for suggesting, as @D.SM pointed out I successfully implemented $project

Like this :-

```
const filter = [{"$match":{"operationType":"update"}}, {"$project":{"fullDocument.user_id": 1, "fullDocument.chats": 0, "fullDocument._id": 0, "fullDocument.first_name": 0, "fullDocument.last_name": 0 }}];
```

Then passed it to `watch()` method

Like:-

```
const userDBChange = userChatModel.watch(filter, { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });
```

Now I'm only getting `user_id` inside `fullDocument` object when the `operationType` is `update` hence reducing the data overhead returned from mongo

Thanks again @D.SM and other's for trying to help me out ;)